# Implementing Oauth2 access token as session

Tags: java, session, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've implemented OAuth2 authorization server using Spring Security and secured restful endpoint. Used resource owner password grant and below is the request flow,

[image: User Authentication Flow Diagram]

I need to maintain user session using access token issued. But, access token works on default expiry time. Came across [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029530/can-should-i-refresh-an-oauth2-token-with-every-request-in-spring-security) that have already discussed on this aspect.

Say, for example, If valid user tries to hit a rest endpoint on 29th minute and again at 31st minute, he might be required to re-login as token would have already expired at 30th minute(access token validity). Though user is active till 29th minute, access token does expire by default timeout.

I'm trying to override token for session functionality. Is there any other approach?

I need clarity on refresh token concept for extending user session or should I update token expiry on each request to client application.

Kindly help if I am completely lost or should I implement another way to handle session in OAuth2 context!

Comment: Did you use [Spring Security OAuth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) project to implement OAuth server? Were you able to figure out answer on how to refresh access token on 29th minute?

Comment: I found that it is possible to override `loadAuthentication` in `ResourceServerTokenServices` to reset access token timer. Have you had a chance to look into it to see if it will work?

Comment: @Maksim: That doesn't sound right, how would you reset an access token timer when it has already been issued and signed?

Comment: Pretty old question without an answer. Did you ever solve this?